# SSD not showing up in BIOS after windows install

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios

The PC has 3 drives, 2 out of 3 were visible in the BIOS (1 is a data disk).

I formatted all drives and installed a fresh Windows 10 copy.

Now only **one** of the 3 SSD shows up in the Bios and I can't seem to boot into windows.

The only one still visible in the BIOS seems to be corrupt, as I can't format or partition it.

When I try to install Windows another time, I can see all 3 SSDs (even though they don't show up in BIOS). I can format 2 out of 3 disks and install to 2 out of 3 disks.

After successfull install windows reboots into a black screen showing the MSI Logo.

Is there anything I could do to troubleshoot this? Could the motherboard / SATA Controller be corrupting the drives?

I'm installing from a USB device.

I went to buy a new SSD. The install worked and it shows up in the bios and I can boot.

Now the GPU died after installing its drivers and doesn't show up in the device manager anymore.

How probable is it that 3 disks die and a GPU die at the same time only by formatting the drives and installing drivers?

Comment: How did you get from 1 failed SSD to 3 without any other failed SSD's being part of the question?  To answer, It is either **extremely probable** or **extremely unlikely** or **neither** more probable than unlikely  depending on **how it/they died.** How about remove the words "**Edit:**" from your question and just edit it to the most current version of the question.  Anyone interested in what and when you edited can see that by clicking on the edited link the site provides.

Comment: @BlindSpots Thanks, for the feedback, I updated the question to be more clear. I'm still puzzled about what caused this.

Comment: What's the make and model of the machine and/or what's the make and model of the motherboard, and what BIOS firmware version are you running. Edit your question and add that detail as well. It could be a power issue where you're drawing too much power than the PSU can provide to all the SSD's and GPU so you might also specify the PSU make and model to get help troubleshoot this issue. Not sure if it's a custom built machine or specific make and model from a particular hardware manufacturer but with that detail and some trivial footwork, someone should be able to help give you a starting point.